# How does the apple website show different content, depending on your internet speed?

Tags: browser, client, user-agent, pagespeed, dynamic-content

I would have phrased this question as 'How do websites measure the client internet speed?' or something. But I feel that this is a much more concrete example, and provides the correct context in which the core question occurred to me.